# Processing json where the number of json array is dynamic

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a json response from php to ajax. The thing is depending on the value entered in a text box the number of json arrays vary. Example: sometimes it may return `{"count1":10, "ccc1":30}` and sometimes like this `{"count1":10, "ccc1":32, "count2":40, "ccc2":123,"count3":32,"ccc3":21}`. I extract the value in jquery this way:

```
success: function(response){
    var count = response.count1;
    //do something
}
```

But now since the number of counts are different I used a loop. Question is I can figure out how many of them I am receiving but how can I process them? The var count = response.count needs to be specific right? I cannot just concate any strings like this:

```
var count = 0;    
while(something){
    count = count + 1;
    var str = "count"+count;
    var whatever = response.str;
}
```

So, can someone please help me with a suitable solution in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track there. Something like this should work for you.

```
var i = 1;
while(response['count' + i]) {
    var count = response['count' + i++];
}
```

You can access the properties as if they were array indices. so `response['count'+i]` works.

Comment: It works for me. Paste this in the browser's console. http://pastebin.com/tGXs6rbs

Comment: I think in my case the response is an object, so its probably not working. Could you please have a look at my code again.

Comment: It will work even if it's an object. The pastebin that I linked also has response as an object. If you can share the entire code I can have a look at what might be failing you. Also make sure the updated js file is being loaded, clear the cache, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through all properties and add them in a variable like following.

```
var response = { "count1": 10, "ccc1": 32, "count2": 40, "ccc2": 123, "count3": 32, "ccc3": 21 };
var count = 0;
for (var prop in response) {
    if (prop.startsWith('count'))
        count += response[prop];
}
console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve all values use `jQuery` `$.each` function.

```js
var data_tmp = '{"count1":10, "ccc1":32, "count2":40, "ccc2":123,"count3":32,"ccc3":21}';
var data = $.parseJSON(data_tmp);
    

   

 $.each(data, function(k,val){
  if(k.toLowerCase().indexOf("count") >= 0){
      $('.wr').append('<div>' + val + '</div>')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wr"></div>
```

Comment: but I need to extract the counts only, you code will include the ccc as well with the counts

Comment: @KimJongUn, updated my example. Now it will include only values of the keys containing `count`

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(response){
var count = response.count1;
    var object = JSON.parse(response);
    alert(object.length);
    for (i = 0; i < object.length; i++) { 
        console.log(object[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does that solve any of OP's problems. It just loops through the json object.

Comment: ist converting the json data into javascript array before looping